# OnsenUI, Angular and refreshing a UI component after an alert dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

I am working on a mobile app using Monaca, OnsenUI and Angular. In a page, I have a list of tappable items; when a user taps an entry, a dialog should appear to enter a value. That value should be displayed in the tapped list item. It does work, kinda, but the value is not refreshed until I tap the list item again, even if only to cancel the dialog. I would like the displayed value to be updated immediately after the user closes the dialog.

Here is an HTML snippet:

```
<ons-page>

  <ons-row style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
    <ons-col ng-controller="NewSubmissionController">
      <ons-list id="materialList" style="margin-top: 12px;">
        <ons-list-header>Pick the Materials</ons-list-header>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-click="doPickMaterial('ferrous')">
          Ferrous (<span ng-bind="materialCounters['ferrous']"></span>)
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-click="doPickMaterial('non-ferrous')">
          Metal, non-ferrous ({{materialCounters['non-ferrous']}})
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-click="doPickMaterial('plastic')">
          Plastic ({{materialCounters['plastic']}})
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-click="doPickMaterial('other')">
          Other ({{materialCounters['other']}})
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
    </ons-col>
  </ons-row>

</ons-page>
```

Here is the controller:

```
app.controller('NewSubmissionController', function($scope) {

  $scope.materialCounters = {
    'ferrous': 0,
    'non-ferrous': 0,
    'plastic': 0,
    'other': 0
  };

  $scope.doPickMaterial = function(matType) {
    ons.notification.prompt({
      title: 'Material: ' + matType,
      message: 'Please enter number of items',
      cancelable: true,
      animation: 'slide',
      callback: function(newCt) {
        alert('Input value: *' + newCt + '*');
        if (newCt != null) {
          if (newCt == '') { //  An empty input will be taken as zero
            newCt = 0;
          }
          $scope.materialCounters[matType] = n;
          alert('Count for ' + matType + ': ' + $scope.materialCounters[matType]);
        }
      }
    });
  };
});
```

I tried both using *ng-bind* and the double curly brackets notation but there was no difference in behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if you want to update the view you can just call `$scope.apply()` manually and everything should update itself. There is probably some "smarter" solution, but since you're using `ons.notification.prompt` this looks like the easiest one.

Comment: It works. I'm not sure I follow why it needs to be called explicitly, since the view updates itself when the model gets altered?

Comment: well basically it checks the value automatically only when something interesting for angular happens. For example if some angular logic is executed it will know to check. In this case however there is nothing which angular itself is doing. A simple example would be if there is some `ng-click` or similar. However if you just execute your logic it will not auto-update. That being said I guess in this case it would be nice if Onsen updates these things by itself since it's a common scenario.